# Pandas Python, as a currency

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a column with currency values, as well as blank values, I want the blanks to be represented at 0.00 and the currency to be in two decimal place values, how would I do this using pandas python?

Comment: Please provide an example of the data as DataFrame constructor

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to alter the visual appearance you can use

```
df.fillna(0).apply(lambda x: ["{0:.2f}".format(item) for item in x ])
```

This will fill all `np.nan` with `0` and then convert the full dataframe to a string with given format-specification. However, this is a very dump approach, since you loose all abilities for calculating with your data.